# Can Multimap contain duplicate value for different key?

Tags: java, multimap

Say,
KEY(+C) contains: A,B,C,D and 
KEY(-C) contains: A,B,C,D. 
The Key-Value pair is not duplicate. Only the values.
Is it legal?

Comment: Of course. The values can be absolutely anything. Why not just try it?

Comment: If it's a multimap, it can contain _whatever_. That's the point, duplicates don't matter. Unless it's a [`SetMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html), in which case the values are stored in a `Set` and there cannot be duplicate values for the same key.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.

Comment: I have another question. Is there any way, I can pass the key to the key-values? Say, I want A,B,C,D to know their key was +C or -C.